# My laptops screen turns black after unplugging from charging

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, charging

My laptops screen turns black after unplugging from charging.
I have tried many things like updating drivers and messing with battery and display settings, but nothing works.

The weird thing is. Display works when it's plugged in and It is charging. Only thing that happenes is screen goes black when unplugging it from AC adapter. External displays works when unplugged. Only the main laptops screen doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue?

Windows 10
Intel i5
Asus x555lb

Comment: Seems the battery is too weak to power the backlight for the internal display.